# Button appears on hover

Tags: raphael

I have a box. when you put your mouse over the box, a button appears on top of the box. the hover function works in such a way that it doesn't recognize that the mouse is still on top of the box. how can I solve it?

```
//I create the paper
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500,500);

//I add the box
var box = paper.add([{
    type: "rect",
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#000',
}])

// I declare a varible for the button
var button

//I add hover functions to the box. 
//first function: when the mouse is on, create a red circle and add an 
//onclick event to the circle
box.hover(function () {
    button = paper.circle(150, 150, 25).attr({ 'fill': 'red' })
    button.click(function () { alert("You clicked me!")})
},
//second function: when the mouse leaves the box, remove the circle
function () {
    button.remove()
})
```

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/V4E4Q/

Comment: This is because you keep creating your button inside the hover and removing it inside the hover out function. Any movement inside that box will try and recreate the button. Create the button outside your box.hover and hide it, you show when you hover and hide when you mouse out. Finally have a flag that says you hovered already, to stop it continually showing everytime you move, reset that flag when mouse out.

Comment: @Neil I did as you suggested but it doesn't fix the problem. The real problem is when I move the mouse over the red button, it is regarded as if I've stopped hovering the rectangle and activates the hide function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to deal with events from different objects one way or another, either I guess with a couple of handlers, or with one that has event propagation and handling possibly, or group with a set. The current event is coming from the button when its displayed, so the event logic doesn't quite make sense as it is. So you could add a handler to the button as well (edit, or use a set for example).

One example would be...

```
        var button = paper.circle(150, 150, 25).attr({ 'fill': 'red' });
        button.hide();
        button.click( function() { alert("button clicked"); } );

        box.mouseout( function() { button.hide() });
        button.mouseover( function() { button.show(); });
        box.mouseover(function () { button.show(); } );
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it should work. jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/V4E4Q/1/

Edit: Another possibly cleaner way could be to group the elements into a set and handle the click. Here is a modified example http://jsfiddle.net/V4E4Q/3/